# Why does method_getNumberOfArguments return two more results than the selector would imply?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

In the objective-C runtime, why does method_getNumberOfArguments return two more results than the selector would imply?

For example, why does @selector(initWithPrice:color:) return 4?

Comment: You might also find this relevant and interesting:

http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/12/18/objc_msgsend-part-1-the-road-map/

Comment: @bbum `[self shamelessPlug]` much? No, I kid, that's a great article for beginning to delve into the runtime.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## TL;DR

Alright. Just to set the record straight, yes, the first two arguments to any objective-c method are `self` and `_cmd`, always in that order.

## A brief history of Objective-C

However, the more interesting subject is the *why* to this scenario. To do that, we must first look into the history of objc. Without further ado, let's get started.

Way back in 1983, Brad Cox, the 'God' of objective-c, wanted to create an object-oriented runtime-based language *on top of* C, for good performance and flexibility across platforms. As a result, the very first Objective-C 'compilers' were just simple preprocessors of Objective-C source converted to their C-runtime equivalents, and then compiled with the platform specific C compiler tool.

However, C was not designed for objects, and that was the most fundamental thing that Objective-C had to surmount. While C is a robust and flexible language, runtime support is one of it's critical downfalls.

During the very early design phase of Objective-C, it was decided that objects would be a purely heap-based pointer design, so that they could be passed between any function without weird copy semantics and such (this changed a bit with Obj-C++ and ARC, but that's too wide of a scope for this post), and that <s>every method should be self aware</s> (acually, as bbum points out, it was an optimization for using the same stack frame as the original function call), so that you could have, in theory, multiple method names mapped to the same selector, as follows:

```
// this is a completely valid objc 1.0 method declaration
void *nameOrAge(id self, SEL _cmd) {
    if (_cmd == @selector(name)) {
        return "Richard";
    } 
    if (_cmd == @selector(age)) {
        return (void *) (intptr_t) 16;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

This function, then could be theoretically mapped to two selectors, `name` and `age`, and perform conditional code based on which one is invoked. In general Objective-C code, this is not too big of a deal, as it's quite difficult with ARC now to map functions to selectors, due to casting and such, but the language has evolved quite a bit from then.

Hopefully, that helps you to understand the *why* behind the two 'invisible' arguments to an Objective-C method, with the first one being the object that was invoked, and the second one being the method that was invoked on that object.

Comment: A couple of corrections. Reference counting wasn't introduced until the OpenStep APIs (~1993).  Originally, ObjC memory management was treated exactly like malloc()/free() w/reference management left as an exercise to the coder.  The first two args being (id, SEL) is purely because it enables tail call optimization by allowing the stack frame to remain unmodified across dispatch.  While you could implement multiple selectors w/one function, as you demonstrate, that was never a goal of passing the SEL as the second argument.

Comment: @bbum I wasn't around in 1993, so thanks for pointing that out. I also never thought about the stack frame, but makes sense when you take a peek into the method dispatch assembly.

Comment: Yeah, I'm old. :)  I started writing ObjC in 1988.

Answer (score 2):

The first two arguments are the hidden arguments self and _cmd.

Comment: You should probably expound on **why** this is.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly why yet. After reading the Objective-C runtime reference (Apple version) I was surprised by the actual outcome of invoking the method -  the extra two weren't described in the docs. . . I just found the answer embedded in another stack-overflow question, and thought it might help others to post it up here. . . If someone wants to expound further, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Sure, I'll expound. Give me a few minutes.